# data synchronization between local system and a remote central server

Tags: postgresql, rest, data-synchronization

**Scenario:** There are many local servers (500+) and a central remote server. client application connects to local server to perform some business process and the resulting data is saved in the local data store (PgSQL with many tables)

Requirements:

- application should be able to switch to the central remote server
  anytime and continue to work. For this to happen, data needs to be replicated and synced (near real-time data sync) between the local servers and the central remote server

Any suggestions??
It would be easier if there was just one table to sync ( store the final state of the data). Instead, the data is spread across multiple tables.

Answer (score 0):

There is both an [FAQ](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/FAQ#What_replication_solutions_are_available.3F) and [an entire section](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Replication,_Clustering,_and_Connection_Pooling) in the postgres documentation devoted to this topic.

I suggest you read the [comparison matrix](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Replication,_Clustering,_and_Connection_Pooling#Comparison_matrix) and see what best fits your use case.

As it stands, your question is too broad to offer any meaningful answer to... but probably the answer is, there's no really good, out of the box solution for this in postgres; pick one of the 3rd party solutions, and ask a more specific question about how to configure / use that solution.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.